# Receiving HTML Instead of JSON after 'ng build'

Tags: angular, express, angular2-routing, mean-stack

I am creating a MEAN stack app, and on the home page I display the posts from the admin. Through 'ng serve' my app works like a charm; however, once I 'ng build' the application, everything seems to fall to pieces.

I receive no errors through 'ng serve':
[image]

But I do after 'ng build':[image]

The error leads to this block of code (`home.component.ts`):

```
 // Get Posts
 this.authService.getRequest("/", false).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.posts = data.posts;
 }, err => {
    if(err) throw err;
    return false;
 });
```

Which calls this (`auth.service.ts`):

```
// Get Request
getRequest(url, authorize) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    if(authorize) {
        this.loadToken();
        headers.append("Authorization", this.authToken);
    }
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000" + url, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Which calls (`users.js`):

```
// Home
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Post.getPostsByUsername('derplicity', (err, posts) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!posts) {
            return res.json({
                success: false,
                msg: 'No posts',
            });
        } else {
            return res.json({
                success: true,
                msg: 'Posts found',
                posts: posts,
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Which finally calls (`post.js`):

```
// Find Posts Using Username
module.exports.getPostsByUsername = (username, callback) => {
    const query = {
        username: username,
    };
    Post.find(query).sort({
        date: 'descending',
    }).exec(callback);
};
```

I looked through the contents of res in `auth.service.ts` and found in 'ng serve' it logs:[image]

And after 'ng build' it logs:[image]

I guess my question now is, why is it receiving HTML and how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: I suppose it may be problem with service, where u take JSON from localhost. Have you tried to put JSON file in `assets` and return `this.http.get(assets/YOUR_JSON`)?